# \emph not working when fontspec is loaded

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, emphasis

The following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    test \emph{emph} \textit{textit} \textbf{textbf}
\end{document}
```

outputs this:

[image: Example output]

i.e. the `\emph` command is not working.
There are no error messages or warnings.
Removing the line `\usepackage{fontspec}` produces the expected result (“emph” in italics).
The result is the same regardless whether LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX is used.
What’s going on?

Using updated TeX Live 2016 on Linux.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with fontspec.